# Limit time in v-calendar datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, vcalendar

I am working on a project where user request for appointment.  I am using `v-calendar`  which uses the `datepicker`.

I am facing a issue where  user can request for appointment  any time/ 24 hours which I need to set only for **9am - 5pm**. I can see that we can limit date in date picker by using something like `:max-date="value"` but could not found how to limit the time.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-framework-1qtjr?file=/src/components/Calender.vue) is the working fiddle

some code from the project

```
    name="appointment-date"
    v-model="appointment_date"
    mode="dateTime"
    :is24hr="false"
    :min-date="currentDate"
    :model-config="dateTimePickerConfig"
    :popover="{
    visibility: 'click',
    placement:  'auto',
 }"
    :masks="{ inputDateTime: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mmA'}">
    <template v-slot="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
        <div class="form-icon ">
            <input-component
                :value="inputValue"
                v-on="inputEvents"
                placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY h:mmA"
            />
            <Icon name="date-time"/>
        </div>
    </template>
</date-picker>
```

Your help to solve the problem will be higly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: have you found answer for this?

Comment: @webkit unfortunately I didn't find any answer for this datepicker.

Comment: @webkit https://ant.design/components/time-picker/ this may help you. antd time picker has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you want to restrict picking specific hours. This is possible with v-calendar with the following property:

```
<v-date-picker v-model="date" :valid-hours="[0,3,4,5,8,16,20]" is24hr />
```

Please note the :valid-hours attribute. You can provide which hours should be available for the user to pick. If you want to allow them to pick minutes in specific 'intervals' you can use following as well:

```
<v-date-picker v-model="date" mode="dateTime" :minute-increment="15" />
```

Note :minute-increment property. This will allow user to pick between '15 minutes. So available numbers will be 00, 15, 30, 45. You can play with it.

Unfortunately, there is no way to disable minutes, which makes me sad. As if someone books appointment at 9:15 AM you would rather want to 'disable' 9:15 AM for next users. You could disable whole hour (9 AM) but not specifically 9:15, so that 9:00, 9:30 and 9:45 would still be available. At least I don't know any easy way.

Hope this helps anyone.

================ **UPDATE** =================
Note that v-calendar added those additional properties in specific v-calendar version. I've been using it with v2.4.*, seems like v2.3.* does not have it yet.

Comment: thanks for you answer . but sending  `valid-hours` as props did not changed anything . can u have a look on the example fiddle ?

Comment: @SandeshSapkota Hm, I've tried in the provided fiddle and to be honest, it does not work there. I might be totally wrong but I assume its because of the version used?

valid-hours and minute-increment are available since v2.0

In my personal project (vue.js) I've installed v-calendar with NPM command and import it inside main.js file.
`import Calendar from 'v-calendar/lib/components/calendar.umd'`  
`import DatePicker from 'v-calendar/lib/components/date-picker.umd'`

Comment: @SandeshSapkota

In my package.json the version I am using is as follows:   
`"v-calendar": "^2.4.1"`  

And I can successfully use commands mentioned above.  
  
Here is the url to the v-calendar:  
[V-CALENDAR](https://vcalendar.io/datepicker.html)  
  
I hope this will help a bit. First of all I would suggest to check version that you are using.

Comment: @SandeshSapkota I've changed v-calendar version on fiddle to match mine and its working, so its all about the v-calendar version that you using.

[Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigilant-robinson-dgfn14?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) - If I embed it correctly you should be able to see it here